# maxReceivedMessageSize and maxBufferSize in app.config

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, service-model

How to increase maxReceivedMessageSize and maxBufferSize parameters in app.config file to 2000000 before running the application.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to do that on your binding, but you'll need to do it on **both** Client **and** Server. Something like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding maxBufferSize="64000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="64000000" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks @mattytommo,this is what i wanted.

Comment: Thank you! It works for me as well. It works even when I provide this change for client only.

Comment: perfect, you saved me a lot of time :) ++1

Comment: I don't get why this answer has so many upvotes. It is wrong, you are not required to set those values on both the client and the server. See my answer below.

Comment: Your little bold words are life-saving.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You can do that in your app.config. like that:

```
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
```

(The max value is `Int32.MaxValue` )

Or in Code:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Name = "MyBinding";
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
```

**Note:**

If your service is open to the Wide world, think about security when you increase this value.

Comment: I don't have app.config file, where i can create it?

Answer (score 15):

The currently accepted answer is incorrect. It is **NOT** required to set `maxBufferSize` and `maxReceivedMessageSize` on the client and the server binding. It depends!

If your request is too large (i.e., method parameters of the service operation are memory intensive) set the properties on the server-side, if the response is too large (i.e., the method return value of the service operation is memory intensive) set the values on the client-side.

For the difference between `maxBufferSize` and `maxReceivedMessageSize` see [MaxBufferSize property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844111/maxbuffersize-property).

Comment: I'm not sure why we have to bother to set the limits at all. What if I don't know how large a payload's going to be (think cardinalities of 0..n)?

Comment: You should always have a protection against "too large". Otherwise you're wide open to DoS attacks.

Comment: Safety aside (which really shouldn't be neglected for public facing services), you won't know at compile-time the amount of data you might send or retrieve from a service call (think object graphs f.e.). You can only estimate. I think [Large Data and Streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming) is of interest, especially the chapter "Special Security Considerations for Large Data".

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a custom binding, you can set the values like this:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="x">
        <httpsTransport maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open app.config on client side and add maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize attributes if it is not available

**Original**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Service1Soap"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

**After Edit/Update**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Service1Soap" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution: Check if it works for you..

Goto web.config

Find binding used by client.

change as,

maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"

Done.

Answer (score 0):

```
binding name="BindingName" 
maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152" 
maxBufferSize="2097152" 
maxBufferPoolSize="2097152"
```

on client side and server side