# MaxBufferSize property?

Tags: c#, wcf

I always thought, that the WCF BasicHttpBinding option `MaxBufferSize` is intended to protect me from DoS attacks, however, the following note in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxbuffersize(v=vs.95).aspx) is weird:

> If a message exceeds the maximum value set for the buffer, it is not dropped. Instead, more memory is requested from the CLR heap and this incurs more garbage collection overhead than using the buffers.

So it looks like the property `MaxBufferSize` is more of a default value and not a *MaxBufferSize*. Do I miss something?

Comment: Well, it does exacly what it implies it does. It is the biggest chunk your application will accept, packets can be smaller,anything larger will come in <insert size here> chunks

Comment: What exactly is a "package"? In the end a method is called in my service and it receives all the parameters at once. No concept of "packages" anymore...so all the memory must be allocated at the same time. Or is MaxBufferSize only relevant for streaming contracts?

Comment: think of it as a way of tuning your app. As it says, requests over the maxbuffer size are not dropped, eg, if you set it to be 5k, and someone sends you 1gb, you will get 200(ish) chunks which have greater overhead than if you set your your max buffer to 1gb (ok, some exageration going on)a "package" would be a request surely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer, thank you BugFinder for the hint into the right direction.

`MaxBufferSize` is indeed important only in *streaming* scenarios. In *buffered* WCF scenarios, it must be set to the same value as the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` (otherwise a configuration exception is thrown). `MaxReceivedMessageSize` is the one saving us from DoS attacks (hard limit).

Comment: i am using c# wcf service in my java application in that where i configure this MaxBufferSize